# Importing CSV file in Neo4j Linux Server

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have installed Neo4j Enterprise edition 3.3.0 in my Linux server machine.

Now i am trying to access the server through my windows machine using port 7474, xx.xx.xx.xx:7474

But the problem is whenever i want to import any csv file to the database, first i have to upload the file into the "import" directory in the Linux server.

Is there any way i can directly import the file which is in my local windows machine into the Neo4j database without having to upload the file into the Linux server first?

Can I create more than one database? If yes how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it in Neo4j, the execution of the query is done on the server side, so the url of the CSV file is related to the server.

But you can have a shared folder with the server, or you can also publish your CSV file on an HTTP server.